# How to copy a file into Javadoc's {@docRoot}?

Tags: javadoc

The [Javadoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#docRoot) shows the following as an example of how to display the contents of a copyright.html file on each Javadoc-generated page, using {@docRoot}.

```
javadoc -bottom '<a href="{@docRoot}/copyright.html">Copyright</a>'
```

My question is: how can I create the *copyright.html* file in {@docRoot}?

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: Huh, just create that file in that directory. `@docRoot` is just your root documentation folder, nothing else.

Comment: I was thinking there would be a Javadoc mechanism (e.g., similar to doc-files), but I guess not. This certainly works, though. Thanks!